# Scrollmagic scene speed with automatic trigger on page load

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm struggling to understand how to manage the speed of the scene I set as intro.
It starts automatically when the page is loaded but currently it is too slow.

It is probably something easy but I'm a new user.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var tween100 = TweenMax.fromTo( '#intro', 25,{opacity: 0, y: 50}, {opacity: 1, y: 0});
    var tween100 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#trigger_intro',
        triggerHook: 'onEnter', 
        duration: 0, 
        offset: 0, 
    })
        .setTween(tween100)
        .addIndicators() 
        .addTo(controller);
    });
```

https://codepen.io/Freddan3/pen/YzaJvxy

Comment: Hey, you  should try GSAP's Scroll Trigger plugin, plus you should use the latest GSAP version and syntax:
https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/
GSAP Docs:
https://greensock.com/docs/

Comment: Hey @Rodrigo, thanks for your answer, it was a big help!! I solved it!!